# Django-admin won't allow me to modify user permissions and groups

Tags: django, django-admin

When editing user model through admin interface, here's what I see:
[image]
And here's what I expect to see:
[image]
The second one allows me to modify the user permissions, the first one does not.

The User model I use on the first screenshot inherits from `AbstractUser` and is registered in the following way:

```
from django.contrib import admin

import accounts.models


admin.site.register(accounts.models.User)
```

In my settings:

```
DEBUG = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

What can be the problem? How do I get from the first screenshot to the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the actual problem was that I inherited not from `AbstractUser` but from `AbstractBaseUser` and forgot about `PermissionsMixin` (the mixin adds the apropriate fields). So I should've done something like [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L288).

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue but the solution is quite simple. In your admin.py file just add 'groups', 'user_permissions' to filter_horizontal = ()
i.e

```
filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions')
```

that is basically it.

referenced from:
https://djangobook.com/customizing-change-lists-forms/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case is that, I was inheriting only from admin.UserAdmin, I had to create a UserAdmin class that inherits from admin.ModelAdmin and add the filter_horizontal to it, I'm adding the filter every time I modify the UserAdmin, it should look like:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User

    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions')
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    fieldsets = (
        # ('Zone label',{'fields.....'})
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active',)}),
        ('Personal', {'fields': ('about',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('date_joined',)    

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(User)


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['username']
    filter_horizontal = ("groups", "user_permissions")

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when using custom user following django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example
on UserAdmin class I added on Permissions, fields: "groups", "user_permissions". I also added filter_horizontal = ("groups", "user_permissions"). Also I comment out the filter_horizontal at the bottom

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
# The forms to add and change user instances
form = UserChangeFormAdmin
add_form = UserCreationFormAdmin

# The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
# These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
# that reference specific fields on auth.User.
list_display = ["email", "first_name", "last_name", "is_active", "is_staff", "is_admin"]
list_filter = ["email", "is_active", "is_staff", "is_admin"]
fieldsets = [
    (None, {
        "fields": ["email", "password"]
    }),
    ("Personal info", {
        "fields": ["first_name", "last_name"]
    }),
    ("Permissions", {
        "fields": ["is_active", "is_staff", "is_admin", "groups", "user_permissions"]
    }),
    
]
filter_horizontal = ("groups", "user_permissions")
# add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
# overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
add_fieldsets = [
    (
        None,
        {
            "classes": ["wide"],
            "fields": ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "password1", "password2", "is_active", "is_staff"],
        },
    ),
]
search_fields = ["email"]
ordering = ["email"]
# filter_horizontal = []
```