# After inherited from AbstractUser, Django admin can not change user's permissions any more

Tags: python, django, permissions, admin

I change django user model by  inherited from AbstractUser, codes like the following. But I can not
modify user permissions and change the group which user belong to any more in Django admin site. When I logon to admin as super user, go to the user page. The user'permissions can not be changed. Can anyone help?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib import admin

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)


admin.site.register(UserProfile)

#settings.py add this
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add some code in your admin.py

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ("groups", "user_permissions")
```

Try it.

ref : [Django-admin won't allow me to modify user permissions and groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837617/django-admin-wont-allow-me-to-modify-user-permissions-and-groups)

awkeye7 's answer is proper to me.
:)